# Troubleshooting Voila Deployment on Heroku: App Boot Timeout (H20 Error) with Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, heroku, deployment, jupyter-notebook, voila

I am encountering an issue deploying a Jupyter Notebook using Voila on Heroku, specifically an `H20 App boot timeout` error. The application starts successfully as indicated by the logs, but then it fails to become accessible, resulting in a timeout. [Here's my repo](https://github.com/smazonyrobak/BIOS0030_server2)

Here are the key details:

- Environment: The app is a Jupyter Notebook being served through Voila on Heroku.
- Error Observed: The primary issue is a `H20 App boot timeout` error from Heroku. This occurs after the logs indicate that Voila has successfully started and is running.
- Log Details: The logs show that Voila is using the `/tmp` directory for connection files and serving static files from the appropriate location. However, Voila appears to be running at `http://localhost:port_number/`, which seems unusual for a Heroku deployment.

Procfile Configuration: My `Procfile` is set up as follows:
`web: voila --port=$PORT --no-browser --strip_sources=True All_tests_launcher/all_tests_launcher.ipynb`

Attempts to resolve:
I’ve tried ensuring Voila binds to 0.0.0.0 instead of localhost and checked for any long startup times or blocking operations in the notebook. The notebook runs fine locally.

I am seeking insights into why this error is occurring and how to resolve it to get the Voila app running smoothly on Heroku.